# Date Javascript functions giving different result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run this to my browser and getting different result and when convert it in python to get date i am getting two different date also. why?

enter code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to display the numbers of milliseconds between a specified date and midnight January 1, 1970.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p> UTC </p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p> get Time method</p>
<p id="UTC"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var d = Date.UTC(2016, 03, 10);
var dt=  new Date(2016, 03, 10);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
document.getElementById("UTC").innerHTML =dt.getTime(); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: UTC !== local time

Comment: but when i am converting it in python datetime i am getting this print datetime.fromtimestamp(1460246400000/1000.0) : -
2016-04-10 05:30:00
print datetime.fromtimestamp(1460226600000/1000.0) :-
2016-04-10 00:00:00

Comment: The different hours/minutes are the difference between UTC and your local timezone. The "wrong" month is because the month parameter in `Date(y, m, d)` is zero-based. `0 = january, 1 = february, ...`

Comment: thanks @Andreas  for your suggestion. It's working fine for me now.